# Pepper android sdk emulator error on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-18.04, pepper

I am trying to start the robot-emulator from pepper android sdk. But i am having this error when i try to start the emulator.

Below is the error i am getting

```
ROBOT_VIEWER_EMULATOR : /home/hassaan/.local/share/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK/API 4/tools/bin/robot_viewer: /home/hassaan/.local/share/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK/API 4/tools/bin/../lib/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
```

Has anyone run in the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure your user is in the kvm group.

You need to first install this:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

To check the ownership of /dev/kvm use:

```
ls -al /dev/kvm
```

The user was root, the group kvm. To check which users are in the kvm group, use

```
grep kvm /etc/group
```

This returned

```
kvm:x:some_number:
```

on my system: as there is nothing rightwards of the final " : ", there are no users in the kvm group.
To add the user yourname to the kvm group, you could use

```
sudo adduser yourname kvm
```

which adds the user to the group, and check once again with grep kvm /etc/group.
You might want to log out and back in (or restart) for the permissions to take effect.

2. Relink the correct libz.so

Go to: `/home/yourname/.local/share/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK/API 4/tools/lib`

Back up the old `libz.so.1`:

```
mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.bak
```

And relink the system's one:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so libz.so.1
```

3. Restart Android Studio

You should now be able to start the Pepper emulator!